# 408 ошибка при подключении софтфона

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx

Установил CentOS 7 + asterisk 13 + FreePBX 13 на виртуальной машине VirtualBox, все вроде как завелось и работает но при попытке подключения софтфона MicroSIP с хост-машины возникает ошибка, что превышено время ожидания запроса.

Что сделано:

1. Открыты порты 5060,5061,10000-20000
2. Перепроверены все настройки freePBX и астериска - все должно быть правильно

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? Гугл толком тоже не помог..

Comment: tcpdump на сервере запустите и посмотрите, что приходит от софтфона (или нет) и что отвечает сервер (и куда)

Comment: Спасибо, помогли найти в чем дело)

Answer (score 1):

Помогло открытие всех портов iptables:

> iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
>
> iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
>
> iptables -F

Comment: Хорошее решение для тестов и отладки, но лучше разобраться какие реально требуются порты и спрятать остальные за брандмауэром.